# Why can't I import a package in anaconda jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am working with anaconda and the jupyter notebook. In anaconda, I have my own environment, in which I loaded my packages. So now I loaded the anfis package, found on github. Everything went fine, I opened the terminal and typed `pip install anfis` and there where no problems, like with every other package I installed.

But if I open the jupyter notebook, this error shows up:

[image]

I read a lot on the internet but I am not (!) a programmer and I don't really understand what to do, or I tried it and it did not work....

Edit: I followed the comment below and was able to import anfis, but now I can't handle the membershipfunction or anything else, I just can import anfis, so my problem is NOT solved:(

To import anfis correctly, I did the following: I just copied the `membershipfunction.py` and `mfDerivs.py` from the `member` folder to the `anfis` folder, removed in the "anfis-init" everything expect `import anfis`, and in the `anfis.py` I wrote

```
import membershipfunction
import mfDerivs
```

So I can do now:

```
import anfis
```

without an error, but if I do for my defined membershipfunction sth like

```
mfc = anfis.membershipfunction(mf)
```

or anything else the error NoModuleError or NoAttributeError occurs

Comment: see also: https://github.com/twmeggs/anfis/issues/4 - seems to me that the code on pypi is written for python2 and you probably installed it into a python3 interpreter

Comment: thank you, it helped a bit, but now i can import anfis, but then if i want to use the membershipfunction or sth the same error occurs.....

Comment: Can you share the contents of the Conda environment?

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution: The link, which you see in the comment from cel, helped a little bit to understand the problem. But it does not erase my error completely as i was not able to handle with membershipfunction. The problem was, that `anfis` is just for Python 2, so i created a new environment with Python 2 in my Anaconda Navigator. I did this like here: https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097. With Python 2 you can just do `import anfis`and `from anfis import membership`and this works for me :)